# Twilio Flex Webchat - ability for end user to terminate chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am building an internal support tool with Twilio Flex. The first rollout will just handle chats from either the WebChat widget or SMS. For the WebChat widget, I can't find anything allowing the end user to terminate the chat. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Using the [Flex WebChat Actions framework](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-webchat-actions) you can make a call to `RestartEngagement` which will:

> Remove the user from the chat channel and return them to a pre-engagement stage.

If you want the end user to control this you can create a plugin that includes an extra button in the UI that, when pressed, triggers this action and resets their state.

Let me know if that helps at all.